# Using a UITableView to populate a UITabBar

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uitabbar

I am converting my single view application into one that is based on tabs. I have most of the layout done so I'm trying to wire up all the components now and I'm stuck trying to figure out how to do two things:

1. When I pick a bonus from my `UITableView`, I want it to open my 2nd tab with the info for the selected row. I'm not sure how to do that.
2. If I go straight to one of the other tabs, I want to have it just display the details for the first visible row of the `UITableView`. I'm not sure how to set such a default value.

I'm not exactly sure what code you would need to see for the above, but I am using Xcode 9 and Swift 4. I've googled and searched [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/) and [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/), and the answers are either all for Objective-C or are about the `UITabBar` obscuring the last row of `UITableView` data (which is not an issue I'm having).

EDIT: I seem to have semi-gotten it to work by changing my `prepare (for segue)` and then via Interface Builder, deleting the segue from the UITableView to the tab's viewController. However, this still doesn't light up the proper tab in the UITabBar. Also, this is still wrapped in the original Navigation Controller. Which allows me to move back and forth, but isn't the intent. When I tried removing the Navigation Controller, I had to use a "Show" or "Modal" type segue, which covers up the UITabBar, and offers no way to get back out of the detail view. I want to use the UITabBar to provide the back and forth that the Navigation Controller used to handle so I can gain the space at the top of the screen back.

Comment: by the sound of it you don't need a tab view for that requirements. its basic navigation view (or split view controller). but if you really wanna use tab bar just use some global class (singleton may be, very easy in Swift) to keep the data source(an array or a dictionary) and also keep the selected row as a globally accessible parameter in that class, and use viewWillAppear method to check it and show details when displaying each view

Comment: The original version of the app used a navigation controller with a UITableView, a Detail view that contained a UIScrollView to hold all the data, and then a settings view. It is functional, but kinda ugly. The new design idea is to show the list of bonuses on the first tab, then the second tab is to capture it (take photo), 3rd tab is information about that bonus, and the 4th tab is settings. To get to where I am now, I embedded the existing Navigation Controller into a Tab View Controller. And have begun to separate the detail view into the two halves (capture and info).

Answer (score 1):

The simplest is probably to register a Notification Center observer in your second tab's view controller.  Whenever you have an item to show, simply trigger the notification from your first tab's view controller attaching the object you need to show to the notification.

Comment: I'm gonna let my newbie flag fly high here and admit I don't know what you mean by "register a Notification Center observer". Does this link look like the right path for me to start down? [https://learnappmaking.com/notification-center-how-to-swift/](https://learnappmaking.com/notification-center-how-to-swift/)

Comment: I look into that further and one of the statements was "Say you have a View Controller A and a View Controller B. You want to pass some data from A to B, when B is shown on screen. Do you use the notification center? No!" Which seems to be exactly what I'm trying to do. I really just want the "cellForRowAt" in my UITableView to trigger ViewController B and display the info related to the chosen "cellForRowAt".

Comment: @DJFriar right... but you also try to use a UITabBar to display multiple ViewController which typically are permanently allocated once, so in other words, you can't easily re-instantiate a new one every time you tap the cell of view controller A.  If you have a better solution to your own problem, feel free to share! :)